# Rails Column in Schema but not Showing Up in Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I recently ran a migration to add a "Rank" column as a `float` to a model called `jokes` (it's a reddit-type page on the app).  It shows up in my `schema`, which means to me that the migration was successful, but when I try to use it to order things via the controller or when I look for that column in my rails console I don't see it.

Here's an example of the controller ordering that doesn't work:

```
@jokes = Joke.where(kids: true, approved: true).order("rank DESC")
```

And here's the console output which neglects the new "rank" column:

```
[54] pry(main)> Joke.last
  Joke Load (4.7ms)  SELECT  "jokes".* FROM "jokes"  ORDER BY "jokes"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Joke:0x007fb52f927e58
 id: 16,
 title: "Test Joke",
 body: "Tested",
 kids: false,
 mixed: false,
 approved: true,
 rejected: nil,
 user_id: 1,
 created_at: Sat, 13 Aug 2016 19:40:14 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Sat, 13 Aug 2016 19:40:18 UTC +00:00>
```

Can anyone help me figure out what's going on here?

Comment: did you refresh your console?

Comment: @Ren, okay score one point for me being a moron.  Now rank at least appears in the console, but it still doesn't order the jokes by rank.

Comment: @Liz can you show the command you're using to order and the output? Drop it into your question so we can review it and help determine why it's not doing what you're expecting.

Comment: @Liz Have you set a `rank` to the existing records?

Comment: @TylerFerraro, the controller statement above is the way I was trying to order the output (`@jokes = Joke.where(kids: true, approved: true).order("rank DESC"`), but maybe this isn't right?

Comment: @ArunKumar, I have `  def update_rank
    new_rank = points
    update_attribute(:rank, new_rank)
  end` in my `joke.rb` model, but the rank is showing up as `nil`, so I guess that isn't working.  However, when I call `joke.points` a number shows up, which makes even less sense...